# x86 Windows 8 Tablet running Pro can't access Integrated Cameras with Emgu OpenCV

Tags: opencv, windows-8, tablet, emgucv

I can't get Emgu CV to work with the cameras on the new Atom based Windows 8 x86 tablets. These are not the ARM based tablets running Windows 8 RT these are running the full blown Windows 8 Pro x86 on x86 Atom CPUs. I've tried working code on a release version of the Samsung XE500T1C (Ativ?) and on a pre-release version of the HP ElitePad 900.

Emgu CV tells me: "Error: Unable to create capture from camera 0". The problem is probably related to the fact that the new Atom chipset is handling some of the camera functions. I've attached a screenshot of the device manager with the offending cameras highlighted.

Under Imaging devices we have:
Intel(R) Imaging Signal Processor 2300

Under System devices we have:
Camera Sensor OV2720
Camera Sensor OV8830
Flash LM3554

[image: Samsung XE500T1C Running Windows 8 Pro 32-bit]

I've searched the Internets high and low and can't find anything useful. I've contacted HP and they're contacting their engineering. I tried Intel and the best I got was this: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sample-windows-store-app-for-camera-picture-taking which is actually for the Windows Store apps. Although it does work.

Does anyone have any ideas? Needless to say I'm in a bind. One other thing Emgu CV is working fine on my Samsung Slate Series 7 that is running Windows 8 Pro. It also runs fine in a 32-bit Windows 8 Pro VM. It just appears to be these new ones with the new Atoms with the Intel Imaging Signal Processor 2300.

Thanks everyone!

Hal

Comment: This is definitely a problem for me with the new Intel Clover Trail Atoms being used in these tablets.  I can't get any webcam code from anywhere to run on them.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled Emgu back to 2.1.1 from December of 2010. This appears to work fine with the new Intel Clover Trail Atoms.

FYI: I also tried the 2.4.9 Alpha dated 2013-01-14, but that would not work.

Comment: Did you try any of the other versions like 2.2.1

Comment: I have the exact same issue.

Comment: I did not try any other version. If you try something newer than 2.1.1 can you let me know if it works?

Comment: I am working with the HP ElitePad 900 with the exact same camera related hardware. I am trying to use the camera for barcode scanning and am running into the same issues. Were you ever able to find a resolution? Below is a link to my question on codeplex however it is now looking like this is hardware/driver related. Any help would be appreciated! https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/448875